# R - Can I use a seed to continue generating more numbers where I left off?

Tags: r, random-seed, seeding

Assuming I saved my seed, is there a way to continue to generate values from where I left off or do I have to generate everything again?

For example, say I generated three numbers:

```
> set.seed(1);rnorm(3)
[1] -0.6264538  0.1836433 -0.8356286
```

If I wanted to generate three more numbers, I could start over again and generate six numbers,

```
> set.seed(1);rnorm(6)
[1] -0.6264538  0.1836433 -0.8356286  1.5952808  0.3295078 -0.8204684
```

but is there a way to skip the first three numbers and generate the next three only (i.e., 1.5952808  0.3295078 -0.8204684)?

Other posts have mentioned using `.Random.seed` to continue where I left off, but when I save the `.Random.seed` contents before and after a run it's the same.

```
> .Random.seed<-SeedA
> rnorm(3)
[1] -1.2602276  0.4266497  0.3938853
> .Random.seed<-SeedB
> identical(SeedA,SeedB)
[1] TRUE
```

So is there a way to skip ahead that I'm not understanding? Thank you for any responses or feedback

Comment: Once a seed is chosen the random number generator will continue to generate the next random number, it does not depend on whether it is within one function call or multiple.  For example these two statements will generate the same sequence of "random" numbers  `set.seed(1); c(rnorm(3), rnorm(3))` and `set.seed(1); rnorm(6)`

Answer (score 0):

I wonder what is the reason to have the next numbers generated off the same seed? Imagine that after a draw of 3 numbers you need to do some other operation and then continue to draw random numbers. If you would like to have this replicable, can you not set the seed before you draw each set of random numbers to some deterministic value? E.g.

```r
set.seed(1)
rnorm(3)

# Do some other stuff

set.seed(2)
rnorm(3)
```

(you can go as long as you want like this obviously - you can initialise some vector of numbers, and then index into it for setting the seed for any arbitrary number of batches)

Now, even though the second set of 3 random variables will not be the same as if you had drawn 6 numbers with a seed of 1, but if replicability is all that matters, then you can run the above and always get the same random numbers. So, is it important that the random number batches are generated with the same initial seed?